# how to access DIV value in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a div like the following:

```
<td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
<td class="total-value"><div id="total">$20.00</div></td>
```

Now, I want to access that div value in php and want to store it into MySQL. For that I have written the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("index.php");
$total = $dom->getElementById('total');
```

But I its giving me NULL result.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: `$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/index.php'));`

Comment: Do you want  to access the value in same page or different php page?

Comment: @Dev at the same page...

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
function getHTMLByID($id, $html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $node = $dom->getElementById($id);
    if ($node) {
        return $dom->saveXML($node);
    }
    return FALSE;
}
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.mysql.com/');
echo getHTMLByID('tagline', $html);
```

**output////////**

```
The world's most popular open source database
```

Answer (score 0):

try this just you need to use **textContent**

```
 <?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML('<td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
              <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$20.00</div></td>');

$total = $dom->getElementById('total'); 

echo $total->textContent;//$20.00

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
$total = $dom->getElementById('total').innerHTML;

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
total.textContent
```

or

```
total.innerHTML
```

Comment: shall i put this directly into php?

Comment: Not directly as it is, Do like `$total = $dom->getElementById('total').innerHTML`  or `$total = $dom->getElementById('total').textContent`